# How can I let another class know that a button was clicked (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android

Below is the code which I'm using to return a number which should be 1 when the button is clicked. However when I try to get that number from another class, it always stays 0.

As you might recognize, I tried to change the number in the onClickListener and returned it below.

I also tried to use the onPause command so that it will return the number onPause but it still doesn't work.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public int number;
    Button btnAngled;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);



        btnAngled = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAngled);

        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, angledForeheadActivity.class);



        btnAngled.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                number = 1;
                startActivity(intent);

            }

        });


    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

}
```

I try to get the code in another class with:

```
 MainActivity a = new MainActivity();

int number = a.getNumber();
```

Sorry for the noob question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare the variable as static variable. Then you can simply obtain the result you want since there is only one copy of that variable. If you want to pass the value using intent, you can call putExtra() of intent to carry information to another activity. 
[Intent reference page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Comment: One more thing. Your problem is related to static variable and instance variable. Since number is an instance variable, every object would have one copy. Seems you should learn some basics of java first before learning Android.

Answer (score 0):

What you actually want is getting the number from another Class. Don't mix the job with button click together. You should setup the concept of model to store data and seperate UI and data, UI just change/get the data.

I suggest you either of the two ways

1. Store the number in some global model, then you can get the number from another Class.
2. User Android Broadcast to transfer the data

Use static variable in Activity is not a good idea, it may cause memroy leak, though it can solve your problem.